# Can't get artifacts, that were created within a specific date range

Tags: curl, jfrog-mission-control

I need to make a manual cleanup of Jfrog artifactor from old artifacts by using REST API.

For these purposes, first of all, I must identify artifacts, created within a specific date range.

The problem is that when I use

```
curl -u user:password -X GET "http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/search"
```

I get this error

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 405,
    "message" : "Method Not Allowed"
  } ]
```

What does it mean, that method is not allowed? How can I deal with it?

The full command is

```
curl -u user:password "http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/search?from=long&to=long&repos=currentrepo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the rest api wrong.

This is how the full command should look like:
curl -u admin:password "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/search/**dates**?**dateFields=created**&from=1461052559000&to=1492588559000&repos=libs-snapshot-local"